# How to archive all blobs matching a prefix from all containers in an Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure-storage-account

I have a storage account where new containers may be created every day. All these containers have the structure and have a folder called `photos` with some blobs inside.

Ex:

```
containerA/photos/photoA1
containerA/photos/photoA2
containerB/photos/photoB1
```

I'd like to create a lifecycle rule to go through all the containers and archive all the blobs inside `photos` which haven't been updated for 90 days.

Unfortunately, it seems Azure doesn't support regex for the prefixMatch.
I couldn't find any API to programmatically add new lifecycle rules when a new container is created...

Otherwise, another option would be to create an Azure function to upload the blob to the archive-tier and delete it. Surely there's an easier solution(?)

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't fix your issue, but I'm in the same boat as you. Currently we're forced to manage this for archiving logs, by giving the logs the same name. It seems, that then the archiving / moving to cold storage should work. To then discern between specific logs, we give the folder structure a unique structure: /api-one/2022/log.txt, /api-two/2022/log.txt, but really, this would be better if we could just have regex.

Also: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45890#issuecomment-573143903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Microsoft Support:
The workaround is to use "Blob index tags" and to create a rule based on this tag.

Filter set on the rule:
[image: Filter Set]

Adding a tag to a blob (manually or programmatically):
[image: Blob index tag]